# Monotonicity of natural transformations between list and maybe functors

Tags: ct.category-theory, order-theory

Given two endofunctors $\mathit{List}, \mathit{Maybe}: \mathit{Set} \rightarrow \mathit{Set}$ defined as in Haskell with an ordering that preserves the functorial structure:

$$a_1 \ldots a_n \leq_{\overline{\mathit{List}}(A)} a_1' \ldots a_n' \text{ iff } a_1 \leq a_1' \ldots a_n \leq a_n'$$

$$\mathit{Nothing} \leq_{\overline{\mathit{Maybe}}(B)} \mathit{Nothing}$$
$$\mathit{Just}(b) \leq_{\overline{\mathit{Maybe}}(B)} \mathit{Just}(b') \text{ iff } b \leq_B b'$$

How can I prove that natural transformations $\eta: \mathit{List} \rightarrow \mathit{Maybe}$ are monotone?

[image]

Comment: Surely you mean $PoSet$ rather than $Set$ ? Otherwise what's the ordering ?

Comment: No, I really mean $\mathit{Set}$. The functors should extend via an ordering functor $\leq : \mathit{Set} \rightarrow \mathit{PreOrd}$ (see Definition 2.1 in http://phiwumbda.org/~jesse/papers/tcs.pdf).

Comment: There is a problem with your conditions : $f$ is suppose to be a map between mere sets, so it does not make sense to ask for a monotone one. If we replace "monotone" by just "map of sets" in your conditions, then it is juste the definition provided by your link. Then there is no way that an arbitrary $\eta$ will be monotonic (choose for example the indiscrete preorder on $List$ and the discrete one on $Maybe$). Perhaps are you thinking of specific order on $List$ and $Maybe$ ?

Comment: @PierreCagne, I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Your edition does not address the issue. The all point of the definition you linked is to talk about endofunctors $F$ such that $F(X)$ is endowed with a preorder while $X$ isn't. So for example, defining the preorder for $Maybe(B)$, the formula $b\leq b'$ makes no sense because $B$ is not supposed to be a preorder. A preorder that works on $Maybe(B)$ is to say that every $Just(b)$ is smaller than $Nothing$, with no other comparable pairs (special case of 2.2.(2)).

Comment: @PierreCagne, maybe a diagram helps.

Comment: I'm a category theorist and I expect this question is answerable, but it's an effort for me to decipher Haskell-speak, so let me ask some questions. First, is your question whether *every* natural transformation $\eta: \text{List} \to \text{Maybe}$ at the set-level lifts to a transformation at the preorder level? Second, I have a hard time deciphering the definition of $\leq$ on $\text{List}(A)$ for $A$ a preorder. I understand $\text{List}(A)$ to consist of associative words $a_1 \ldots a_n$ in letters of the alphabet $A$. Could you say again without using Haskell syntax when (continued)

Comment: when $a_1 \ldots a_m \leq a_1^\prime \ldots a_n^\prime$?

Comment: @ToddTrimble $a_1 \ldots a_n \leq a_1' \ldots a_n'$ iff $a_1 \leq a_1'$, ... $a_n \leq a_n'$. The lists have to have the same lenghts.

Comment: And $\mathit{Maybe}(A) = 1 + A$, where I name left injection $\mathit{Nothing}: 1 \rightarrow \mathit{Maybe}(A)$ and the right $\mathit{Just}: A \rightarrow \mathit{Maybe}(A)$

Comment: Yes, thanks. And just to clarify, you're asking about all possible $\eta$, yes?

Comment: Yes. All $\eta$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61360/discussion-between-svenk-and-todd-trimble).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's classify the possible natural transformations $\eta: \text{List} \to F$ for any endofunctor $F$ on $\text{Set}$. We have $\text{List}(X) = \sum_{n \geq 0} X^n$, so $\text{List}$ is a coproduct of representable functors $\hom(n, -): X \mapsto X^n$. The set of natural transformations is therefore

$$\text{Set}^\text{Set}(\text{List}, F) \cong \text{Set}^\text{Set}(\sum_{n \geq 0} \hom(n, -), F) \cong \prod_{n \geq 0} \text{Set}^\text{Set}(\hom(n,-), F) \cong \prod_{n \geq 0} F(n)$$

where the last isomorphism is by the Yoneda lemma. For $F = \text{Maybe}$ in particular, a transformation $\eta: \text{List} \to \text{Maybe}$ is specified by a sequence of integers $\mathbf{n} = (n_0, n_1, \ldots)$ where $0 \leq n_k \leq k$ for each $k \geq 0$. It is defined by the rule

$$\eta_\mathbf{n}(x_1\ldots x_k) := x_{n_k}$$

if $1 \leq n_k \leq k$, and $\eta_\mathbf{n}(x_1\ldots x_k) = \mathit{Nothing}$ if $n_k = 0$.

So now I think we just follow our noses. If $x_1\ldots x_k \leq y_1\ldots y_k$ in $\text{List}(X)$, then for each $\mathbf{n} = (n_k)_{k \geq 0}$ we have (in case $1 \leq n_k \leq k$)

$$\eta_\mathbf{n}(x_1\ldots x_k) = x_{n_k} \leq y_{n_k} = \eta_\mathbf{n}(y_1 \ldots y_k)$$

where the displayed $\leq$ follows from the definition of $\leq$ on $\text{List}(X)$, with a similar inequality in case $n_k = 0$. So indeed the transformation $\eta_\mathbf{n}$ is monotone.

Comment: Thank you. I still have a few questions. Why is $\mathbf{List}$ a coproduct of the representable functor?

Comment: My understanding is that $\text{List}(X) = \sum_{n \geq 0} X^n = \sum_{n \geq 0} \hom(n, X)$, i.e., $\text{List} = \sum_{n \geq 0} \hom(n, -)$.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I think I can follow the rest of the proof. Thank you so much, this was very helpful.